# iOS -- "add" methods appearing for autosynthesized properties in codeSense

Tags: ios, xcode, properties, automatic-properties

I just created an iOS class with the following properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* foo;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSObject* bar;
@property (nonatomic) CGRect fubar;
```

I did not put in any @synthesize or explicit ivars for these properties.  I then went into the implementation file and started to create a method as follows:

```
-(void) add
```

I left the cursor at the end of the word "add".  The following method names then popped up in code sense:

```
addBar: (NSSet*) objects
addBarObject: (objectType *) object
addFoo: (NSSet*) objects
addFooObject: (objectType *) object
addFubar: (NSSet*) objects
addFubarObject: (objectType *) object
```

What are these methods?  Are there any docs for them?

Comment: This is the first, and probably unique and last time in my life I **added** the `xcode` tag to a question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That are accessor methods that a class can implement to support Key-Value Coding for mutable to-many relationships, 
see [Mutable Unordered Accessors](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-SW5) in the "Key-Value Coding Programming Guide":

> In order to be key-value coding complaint for a mutable unordered
>   to-many relationship you must implement the following methods:
>
> `-add<Key>Object:` or `-add<Key>:`. At least one of these methods must be implemented. These are analogous to the `NSMutableSet` method
>   `addObject:`.

The same "strange" autocompletion happens for other Key-Value coding accessor methods, 
for example:

```
- (void)remove...
- (void)intersect...
- (NSUInteger)countOf...
```

Comment: OMG! Sometimes the commonness of the words like "add" makes me forget and use `-add<Key>` methods. Then KVO stuffs break when you don't pass the correct object class to it, with weird errors like `-[MYObject intersectsSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc45dde0`. This info is useful indeed. :)