# What is this syntax when I was attempting to override a getter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

What is this syntax when I was attempting to override a getter??

I'm just messing around trying to learn more about how properties work in Objective-C.  Here is my property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *myView;
```

When I try to override the getter I get this help:

```
-(void)getMyView:(<object-type> **)buffer range:(NSRange)inRange
{

}
```

I know I can use this:

```
-(UIView *)myView
{

}
```

But I am just curious as to what the previous method does, why it's there, etc.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm not sure this relates to what you're asking about... but `getters` shouldn't take any arguments and shouldn't return `void`.  A method with a `void` return type doesn't GET anything.

Comment: Does this happen when your property's type is `MyProperty` and is named `myProperty`?  Whatever you're seeing may be something related to the specific class you're using...

Comment: I get the same for my properties. Now I'm very curious as well!

Comment: @nhgrif Yeah, that makes sense that a getter shouldn't return void and take no arguments.  I changed the property so it's more clear that it's not a special case. And the class I'm in inherits from NSObject.

Comment: A splendid example on how SO is all about learning. I didn't know about the existence of such construct and now I going through the whole guide. Thanks for the good question.

Comment: Similar issue here: [iOS — “add” methods appearing for autosynthesized properties in codeSense](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15327444/ios-add-methods-appearing-for-autosynthesized-properties-in-codesense).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called "Getter Indexed Accessors" as explained in the [Key-Value Coding Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html)

From the documentation:

> In order to support read-only access to an ordered to-many relationship, implement the following methods:
>
> `-countOf<Key>` Required. This is the analogous to the NSArray primitive method count.
>
> `-objectIn<Key>AtIndex:` or `-<key>AtIndexes:` One of these methods must be implemented. They correspond to the NSArray methods `objectAtIndex:` and `objectsAtIndexes:`
>
> `-get<Key>:range:` Implementing this method is optional, but offers additional performance gains. This method corresponds to the `NSArray` method `getObjects:range:`.

You can implement such methods for performance reasons, as explained in the guide

> If benchmarking indicates that performance improvements are required, you can also implement `-get<Key>:range:`. Your implementation of this accessor should return in the buffer given as the first parameter the objects that fall within the range specified by the second parameter.

As an example

```
- (void)getEmployees:(Employee * __unsafe_unretained *)buffer range:(NSRange)inRange {
    // Return the objects in the specified range in the provided buffer.
    // For example, if the employees were stored in an underlying NSArray
    [self.employees getObjects:buffer range:inRange];
}
```

Comment: Fantastic!  Thanks for Googling it for me! ;)

Comment: It took me a while to get the correct query :) You are welcome

Comment: But I can still go the old school way without these accessories?